# MYSQL PHP query not inserting data

Tags: php, mysql

This code inserts data from a form into a database named "test" and table named "signup". The insert query is not working:

```
   <?php
    echo"working2";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    echo"woerking";
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test") or die("error connecting");
    echo"woerking1";
        $flag=0;
        $Rno=$_POST['rno'];
        echo$Rno;
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        echo $fname;
            $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $email=$_POST['uemail'];
            $pswd=$_POST['pswd'];
        $repswd=$_POST['repswd'];
```

---

```
        //$choice="select Rollno from signup where Rollno='$Rno' ";
        //$chk=mysql_query($choice);
            //echo $chk;
        //while($row=mysql_fetch_array($chk))
        //{
            //echo "<font color='red'>ROLL-NUMBER ALREADY EXIST!!!!</font>";
            //$flag=1;
        //}
```

---

```
        if($flag==0)
    {
       $query="INSERT INTO `signup`(`Rollno`, `fname`, `lname`, `email-id`,    `password`, `retype`)     VALUES($Rno,'$fname','$lname','$email','$pswd','$repswd')";
*##//query not working##* 
            $tem=mysql_query($query);
                    if(isset($tem))
            {
                echo"REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this realization, maybe you want also to ask a question ?

Comment: What errors have you checked for?

Comment: Using same query in phpmyadmin GUI its working there

Comment: We'd need to see the rest of your code - connection and query execution. I'll close for now, will reopen if you fix and ping me with @halfer.

Comment: Who knows which API you're using to connect with. One line of code isn't enough meat for me to chew on.

Comment: whats the error? whats the table names? whats the database? Not enough information provided

Comment: plz help in inserting data ?

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code! Also make sure you ask a proper question in your post. And don't post the code in the comments, use the edit button! (@Fred-ii- I would love to have a British breakfast tea right now :D )

Comment: *No really....* I wasn't kidding earlier; this isn't enough code for me to sink my teeth into. What is the value of `$Rno` and how are you connecting? `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? None of the above?

Comment: Best I can suggest: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @EshankJain You should also be posting your HTML form. Error reporting will tell you if you have any form elements with no name attribute or other syntax errors, and `mysql_error()` will tell you if there's a problem with your database.

Comment: So, what errors were you getting after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this change to start:

```
$tem=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

That will tell you the problem with the query. Unfortunately it won't tell you about the SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code - but please fix them anyway!

Comment: Good move on the wiki ;-)

Comment: Seems like the OP's got a great big smile on their face.

Comment: Problem was in connecting to the database

Comment: @Eshank, pleased it now works for you. Don't forget to fix the security issues too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="INSERT INTO `signup`(`Rollno`,`fname`,`lname`,`email-id`,`password`,`retype`)VALUES('".$Rno."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."','".$pswd."','".$repswd."')";
```

try it like this..